# Convert collection of IEnumerable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a `IEnumerable` collection of `Car` objects

A Car has a property: Year

Using LINQ, I want to find where there are > 1 cars with the same year and return that list.

I would expect it to have to return an array of lists because if the collection is:

```
Car 1: Year 2010
Car 2: Year 2010
Car 3: Year 2009
Car 4: Year 2009
Car 5: Year 2010
Car 6: Year 2008
```

I would expect one list of 3 for 2010 and one list of 2 for 2009

is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with group by. See [hooked on linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) for more samples

```
var result = from car in cars
             group car by car.year into g
             where g.Count() > 1
             select g
```

now result is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Car>>`, meaning you can do this:

```
foreach(var g in result)
{
    int year = g.Key;
    foreach(var car in g)
    {
        // list the cars
    }
}
```

Comment: No critism of you example but sometimes I wish Linq had an AtLeast(int count) method (I ended up writing one). I know Group probably returns an ICollection<T> under the covers which is optimised in Count() but it still worries me everytime I write or see something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
List<Car> list = null;
IEnumerable<List<Car>> ret = 
    from it in list
    group it by it.Year into g
    where g.Count() > 1 
    select g.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<List<Car>> carsGroupedByYear = 
    cars.GroupBy(c => c.Year) /* Groups the cars by year */
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) /* Only takes groups with > 1 element */
        .Select(g => g.ToList()); /* Selects each group as a List<Car> */
```

Comment: That's exactly the same answer as JaredPar's

Comment: Fluent syntax needed some love.